# tvOS - In-App Purchase returns 0 product in productsRequest- Products still in Review

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, tvos

I am getting 0 products in response of productsRequest call. I am using it on tvOS and I checked all steps I need to do before testing it and everything looks good. Only thing is I am testing it on tvOS simulator. Does anyone know if inapp work/not work on simulator? Or anyone else is facing the same issue?

Code I am using to fetch product info:

```
productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(object: "one_year_subscription") as! Set<String>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did some more research and found that Storekit is not available for tvOS simulator in [Release Notes for tvOS 9.0 beta 3](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/releasenotes/General/RN-tvOSSDK-9.0/index.html).